# can azure service bus (for a topic) send notification to a rest end point (POST)

Tags: http, azure, endpoint, servicebus

I need to azure service bus to notify an end point (Rest - POST) whenever a message comes to a particular topic.

In AWS, it is done this way
[AWS llink](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html)

What is the equivalent in Azure. 
Note: I dont want to write code that will receive the message and then call the end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like finally azure released Azure Event Grid which kinds of does this out of the box.. very similar to AWS SQS + AWS SNS combo

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus is a messaging service, not a Notifications service. As such, it deals solely with messaging, and doesn't create notifications for you.

[AWS combines SQS (Simple Queuing Service) with SNS (Simple Notification Service)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/queues-and-notifications-now-best-friends/) behind the scenes to allow you the functionality you're describing. This is to allow SQS to have a behaviour of events. Azure Service Bus has a native support for [Topics and Subscriptions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/) (if that's what you're looking for). I.e. rather than just sending messages to a queue, the message is sent to a topic and appropriate subscriber(s) will get it.

So the short answer to this question in case you don't want to receive the message and trigger a notification is "no".

Saying that, if you're OK with "serverless" functions (similar to AWS Lambdas), you could use [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-service-bus/) to achieve this goal.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I want an out of box solution like AWS without having to code myself. I am surprised why Azure Service bus is not providing an out of box notification to a http ReST endpoint, as this would be the expectation of many subscribers to expose "what they do with the message" as a ReST service end point over http